# multiple buffer management in C

Tags: c, buffer, eventmachine

What would you recommend I do to buffer multiple streams (each stream would require it's own buffer) in C?

I *sort of* put together a solution in my head:

**This is theoretical "pseudo code"**

```
[ptr, ptr, ptr, ptr ... ]
```

Each `ptr` is a pointer to a struct:

```
{
    stream_id
    buff_ptr
}
```

`stream_id` is the ID of the stream (I have that information) and the `buff_ptr` is a pointer to some `malloc`ed data. Also, the buffers would probably have to be flexible and it'd have to call `malloc` and `free` a lot to make it flexible (at least I *think* it would?

I would basically find the buffer I need by iterating through the array of `ptr`s.

---

So, is that "architecture" good, or is there a better one?

If anyone is wondering "Why the nyan does she need that?!" I've made a server in Ruby/EventMachine, the protocol is really rotten (to say the least) and I don't know how else to handle it... Unless there's a way to force EventMachine to buffer it for me, that would be the **best** solution, I suppose.

Thanks.

P.S: Sorry for the rave! ~

Comment: If `stream_id` was an integer from `0` to `N` you could use an array of `buff_ptr` and not have to search through a list of `struct`s to locate the required stream.

Comment: @hmjd Ah, it's not. I thought it was at first, too. Sometimes it is and sometimes it isn't. It's all a bit random, really. And it almost never starts with a 0, actually--now that I think of it.

Comment: Is there a predefined range for `stream_id` even? If there was you could use a sparse array.

Comment: @hmjd Nope. As far as I gathered it usually starts at some random integer, then increments, but it doesn't increment all the time, sometimes it randomly ~jumps to a random number, then starts incrementing again, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems the only option but you can change a few things:

- Don't `malloc` and `free`. Use `realloc` instead
- Iterating through the list could be OK but if there are a lot of buffers

  - Can you make the caller pass you a pointer to the buffer ?
  - Can you use a hash instead of a list and search by `stream_id` ? For example [`glib2` provides such a hash](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.28/glib-Hash-Tables.html)

Many APIs (for example epoll) allow you to associate a pointer with an id (a descriptor in the case of epoll). When something interesting happens to that id, the API passes you your pointer -> zero search at the expense of 4-8 bytes of memory.

Comment: Is there such a thing as a hash in C? I didn't know there was! *c newbie here ~*

Comment: @withadot. There's no standard one. You can implement it yourself or use a ready-made one (for example [glib2 hash](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.28/glib-Hash-Tables.html)).

Comment: Oh. Fancy that. Is there a simple to "install" it?

Comment: @withadot. Depends on your platform. If you use Unix chances are you already have it. Don't really know about windows.

Comment: I'll mark this answer as accepted because glib is ~heaven~, but include mention of Glib in the answer, too. So, people don't have to dig through comments. xo

Answer (score 0):

Use [libev](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html) to make a simple event loop and let it handle polling file descriptors. There are lots of examples out there and it's manual page (`man 3 libev`) is one of the best I've read.

Just define a few callbacks and create some buffers for your read and write pools. The size of those pools can remain static so long as you block or skip your reads and writes when the buffer fills up or exhausts, respectively.